# Creating a csv file that contains product details magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, csv

I am trying to create a csv, using script that contains the below product attributes in magento 1.

**id, title, description, link, image_link, price, availability**

Has anyone implemented it? Any thoughts how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

customize the code according to your requirement i have written it for one my work where i needed to export products from magento 1. i this code am just taking the sku, id , and price you can take other things as well if you want.

```
    <?php
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.csv'); //you can change the file name here if you want
// Load the Magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);

// Load the product collection

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') //Select everything from the table
 ->addUrlRewrite(); //Generate nice URLs

/*
 For this example I am generating a CSV file,
 but you can change this to suit your needs.
*/
 // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('title', 'sku', 'id', 'price'));

foreach($collection as $product) {
 //Load the product categories
 $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
 //Select the last category in the list
 $categoryId = end($categories);
 
 //Load that category
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
 // Collect details in variables
 $title=$product->getName();
 $sku=$product->getSku();
 $id=$product->getId();
 $sku=$product->getPrice();
 $url=str_replace('export.php/','',Mage::getBaseUrl()).$product->getPrice($product);
 fputcsv($output, array($title, $sku, $id, $price));
}
?>
```

put the script in magento root directtory and then run it in browser like below :- http://127.0.0.1:96/mage/export_products.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the question, let me check if the above code works.

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal did the code worked for you?

Comment: I am checking on it. i will update if it works.

Comment: $userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);  Why used this one ?

Comment: this for loading magento core model

Comment: Warning: require_once(app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in index.php on line 5

Comment: This error appears

Comment: wait am checking the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111124/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-chikku).

Comment: check the updated ans

Comment: Checking the updated answer

Comment: Warning: require_once(app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in index.php on line 5

Comment: where did you placed this file?

Comment: look if this does not work for you then just simply change this line with this require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php');

Comment: Yes that seems to be issue

Comment: I am opening file like localhost/pinterest/

Comment: require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php'); changed this and check

Comment: Sure, let me check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the question, upvote question if you think the question & answer can be helpful.

Comment: Also i am not getting "description, link, image_link, price, availability" attributes in product any thoughts ?

Comment: you need to customize it fetch everything that you need

Comment: Thankyou for the answer to the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111126/discussion-on-answer-by-chikku-creating-a-csv-file-that-contains-product-details).